# How to sort json data by two attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

http://jsfiddle.net/dy8w8r7d/

How to sort JSON data by two attributes?
The fuction below only sorts by `Episode`..

**Goal**:  order by `Episode` ascending then by `Sequence` ascending

```
var data = [ { ArticleId: 2, Episode: 1, Type: 0, Sequence: 0 },
  { ArticleId: 1, Episode: 1, Type: 0, Sequence: 1 },
  { ArticleId: 3, Episode: 2, Type: 0, Sequence: 0 },
  { ArticleId: 4, Episode: 2, Type: 0, Sequence: 1 } ];
```

```js
var data = [ { ArticleId: 2, Episode: 1, Type: 0, Sequence: 1 },
  { ArticleId: 1, Episode: 2, Type: 0, Sequence: 0 },
  { ArticleId: 3, Episode: 1, Type: 0, Sequence: 0 },
  { ArticleId: 4, Episode: 2, Type: 0, Sequence: 1 } ];


function compareEpisodeSequence(a,b) {
  if (a.Sequence < b.Sequence)
    return -1;
  if (a.Sequence > b.Sequence)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
data.sort(compareEpisodeSequence);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Just do the sort twice.  First sort by sequence, and next time sort by episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouls do what you want:

```
function compareEpisodeSequence(a,b) {
  if (a.Episode < b.Episode) return -1;
  if (a.Episode > b.Episode) return 1;
  if (a.Sequence < b.Sequence) return -1;
  if (a.Sequence > b.Sequence) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

If the Episodes are equal then you continue comparing the Sequences